# Estimating total variation distance from a given distribution

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

Given a known distribution supported on a finite set of $n$ elements with probabilities $p_1, \dots, p_n$ and an access to an unknown distribution $q$ is it known what is the number of samples from $q$ that is necessary and sufficient to estimate the total variation distance $||p - q||_{TV}$ up to an error $\epsilon$ with constant probability?

Answer (score 1):

I think recent results from Gregory and Paul Valiant (e.g., http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~gvaliant/papers/VV_stoc11.pdf) imply that you can do this in $O(n/\log n)$ samples and that you cannot do it with less. They discuss the problems of support recovery and entropy estimation, but total variation should presumably behave similarly.